# How to bundle all dynamic content in Angular application for air gapped environment?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, cdn, offline

I am building an angular frontend for an application that will run in an air gapped environment once deployed (no internet). During development I am loading fonts, icons and stylesheets from cdns (google fonts, bootstrap css, etc.).

When deployed in the air gapped environment these resources will obviously not be available.

Is there an elgant way to  package all dynamically loaded elements with the application when building?

If not what makes more sense:

1. Bundle all dynamic content with the application
2. Setup a server in the airgapped environment that hosts the dynamic content

Both of these options would be tecnically possible but I'm not sure what is better for maintainability and information online is quite spares (or I'm missing the right search terms - if this was asked before please point me in the right direction)

---

Additional Info:

ng version outupt:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.4
Node: 16.14.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.5.1

Angular: 12.2.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.4
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.4
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@schematics/angular             12.2.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```